# Observing a radio stream java

Tags: java, observablecollection

So i'm trying it make it stream the radio, which it does fine, But only for about 10 seconds. After that i've been told it is supposed to send a notification to anyone observing it. I either am not recieving this message, or I did something wrong, which is a lot more likely.

```
public class RadioListener implements Observer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RadioPlayer player = new RadioPlayer();
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://stream.xmission.com:8000/kcpw");
            RadioListener r = new RadioListener();
            player.addObserver(r);
            player.playRadioStream(url);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) 
    {
        System.out.println("message: " + arg1);
    }
}
```

This plays the radio for about 10 seconds then just terminates. Not sure why =/

Comment: It is difficult to tell from the small sample of code above.  Can you include the RadioPlayer source?

Comment: No, I just have it as a jar file.

Comment: And there is no stack trace or error message?

Comment: Thats the thing, there is no error. It just finishes it's playing and terminates. No error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I simply had the wrong jar file. Question Closed.